# how to select preceding nodes within a specific parent

Tags: xslt-1.0

Given the following xml

```
   <Root>
 <Employee>
   <service>
     <Record>xxx</Record>
     <Record>yyy</Record>
   </service>
   <service>
    <Record>xxx</Record>
    <Record>yyy</Record>
    <Record>zzz</Record>
   </service>
</Employee>
<Employee>
  <service>
     <Record>xxx</Record>
     <Record>yyy</Record>
   </service>
   <service>
    <Record>xxx</Record>
    <Record>yyy</Record>
    <Record>zzz</Record>
   </service>
</Employee>
</Root>
```

Using XSLT1.0, while transforming the xml for each `<Employee>` the `<Record>` field containing 'xxx','yyy','zzz' should occur only once in the result

```
<Root>
 <Employee>
    <Service>
     <Record>xxx</Record>
     <Record>yyy</Record>
     <Record>zzz</Record>
   </Service>
</Employee>
<Employee> 
  <Service>
  <Record>xxx</Record>
  <Record>yyy</Record>
  <Record>zzz</Record>
 <Service>
</Employee>
</Root>
```

In a for-each loop of Employee I tired using `<xsl:if test='not(preceding::./service/Record=$record)'>`. The test works fine for the first `<Employee>` taking the `<Record>` for 'xxx','yyy','zzz' only once. When the iteration goes to the next `<Employee>` the test condition checks for the `<Record>`values in the first`<Employee>` also and it finds preceding nodes already exisitng with the values'xxx','yyy','zzz', hence i am not able to get the records for the second `<Employee>`.
How to get the `<Record>`s in the second `<Employee>` . Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation uses the Muenchian method for grouping**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kEmpRecordByVal" match="Employee/service/Record"
  use="concat(generate-id(../..), '+', .)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Employee">
  <Employee>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "service/Record
           [generate-id()
           =
            generate-id(key('kEmpRecordByVal',
                            concat(generate-id(../..), '+', .)
                            )[1]
                        )
           ]
     "/>
  </Employee>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided one with different values for the second `Employee` to aid readability):

```
<Root>
    <Employee>
        <service>
            <Record>xxx</Record>
            <Record>yyy</Record>
        </service>
        <service>
            <Record>xxx</Record>
            <Record>yyy</Record>
            <Record>zzz</Record>
        </service>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <service>
            <Record>aaa</Record>
            <Record>bbb</Record>
        </service>
        <service>
            <Record>aaa</Record>
            <Record>bbb</Record>
            <Record>ccc</Record>
        </service>
    </Employee>
</Root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Root>
   <Employee>
      <Record>xxx</Record>
      <Record>yyy</Record>
      <Record>zzz</Record>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Record>aaa</Record>
      <Record>bbb</Record>
      <Record>ccc</Record>
   </Employee>
</Root>
```